# Flutter: Return list of Strings using single string in a specific format

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to upload array of string to firestore. I need to return list of Strings using single string as input.

If the input is 'Firestore'.
I should return list like this:
[f,fi,fir,firs,first,firsto,firstor,firestore]

If the input is 'Google Cloud'.
I should return list like this:
[g,
go,
goo,
goo,
goog,
googl,
google,
c,
cl,
clo,
clou,
cloud]

Comment: Please include your current code. We can check where you went wrong. Looks like you are asking for an algorithm which is applicable to any language.

Comment: `var list = [for (var word in input.toLowerCase().split(' ')) for (var i = 1; i <= word.length; i += 1) word.substring(0, i)];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's a good practice to share what you have already done. Here is a simple way of achieving what you want (excluding white spaces) :

```dart
  String test = 'firestore';
  List<String> chars = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= test.length; i++) {
    if (test.substring(0, i).isNotEmpty) {
      chars.add(test.substring(0, i));
    }
  }
  print(chars);
```

The above prints `[f, fi, fir, fire, fires, firest, firesto, firestor, firestore]`

Comment: With this code you will have [G, Go, Goo, Goog, Googl, Google, Google , Google C, Google Cl, Google Clo, Google Clou, Google Cloud] as results ans not [G, Go, Goo, Goog, Googl, Google, C, Cl, Clo, Clou, Cloud] as expected by @ExternalUse Take a look at my response.

Answer (score 0):

For having [g, go, goo, goo, goog, googl, google, c, cl, clo, clou, cloud] as result

use this :

```
  String test = 'Google Cloud';
  List<String> chars = [];

  for (var word in test.split(" ")) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
      if (word.substring(0, i).isNotEmpty) {
        chars.add(word.substring(0, i));
      }
    }
  }

  print(chars);
```